# User-defined function calculating production growth with variable start dates and growth profile

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

Struggling with an excel user defined function to calculate a total production generated by different bacteria patches starting at different times but following the same growth pattern;  I have tried to simplify my problem below:

[Example tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGMFv.jpg)

*PROFILE table:* I have a 2 columns x 6 rows Table (A2:B9) showing a bacteria production per week depending on the age of the colony (column A gives the period, column B the production:  in the first 3 weeks the bacteria produce 1/week in the next 3 weeks they produce 2 per week etc); I call this table my production PROFILE, this may vary depending on the type of bacteria I have (and other environmental parameters).  I have decided in this particular example, and to keep it simple to show the population growth per period in a table, the growth values could of course be generated by a function (linear, exponential, with a decay factor etc) I guess that if I can crack the problem, adding a level of complexity with a growth function shouldn't be an issue.

*RESULT table:* I then have a 3 columns 20 rows table (A14:C33) which shows over a 20 week period (my 20 rows, numbered 1 to 20 in column A) when I start some bacteria cultures (1 in week 3, 2 in week 6 etc), I call it my RESULT table

I'd like to show in column C of the RESULT the total production of the colonies for each week.
I tried creating a PROD(week, PROFILE) function where I defined both "week" and "PROFILE" as variants and where "PROFILE" actually relates to my PROFILE table.  It works fine when "week" is an individual cells (ie PROD(A18,PROFILE)=2) but doesn't work with ranges (PROD(A14:A33,PROFILE) returns an error message)

```
Function PROD(period As Variant, profile As Variant) As Variant
r = profile.Rows.Count

If profile(1, 1) >= period Then
PROD = profile(1, 2)

Else

For i = 2 To r

If profile(i, 1) >= period Then
If profile(i - 1, 1) < period Then

PROD = profile(i, 2)

End If
End If
Next i

End If

PROD = Application.Round(PROD, 2)

End Function
```

is there an elegant solution to populate column C of RESULT?

I did a similar thing on a previous assignment (finance) combining a sumproduct with the excel pmt function  ( -pmt(rate, nper, pv,..)  where pv was a range) and this did work,  I managed to get a nice calculation of my total depreciation cost on a given period when I could have had items purchased in different quantities and at variable prices over the previous periods. the formula I used back then, shown on the attached [Example of DepTable&Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAPrQ.jpg) is

```
SUMPRODUCT(-PMT($C$7,$C6,$C$3:$V$3),N($C$4:$V$4<=C$2),N(($C$4:$V$4+$C6)>C$2))
```

I tried to replicate it here with a custom function with my bacteria population but I am really stuck.

Comment: Maybe this night I'm particularly fatigued, but can't get what you want. Perhaps adding an image of a sample PROFILE and RESULT tables (including desired result) might help. Or just wait a little bit for a lively folk...

Comment: If you pass a range in as your `period` parameter, you will need to use it as an array, i.e. in a similar way to what you have done with your `profile` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite imagine what your profile table might look like nor, in fact, what exactly you want to extract. Perhaps my attempt below gives you some ideas. Please study it and let me know where it needs improvement.

```
Function PROD(period As Variant, profile As Variant) As Variant
    Dim Fun As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    R = 1        ' should this always be 1?
    Do
        Fun = Fun + profile(R, 2).Value
        R = R + 1
        If R > profile.Rows.Count Then Exit Do
    Loop While profile(R, 1) >= period
    PROD = Application.Round(Fun, 2)
End Function
```

I wouldn't use this as a UDF, however. Instead, I would modify it slightly to write directly into the C column. Let the function be called from the Worksheet_Change event, linked to the profile table, or perhaps both tables, so that the data update automatically whenever there is a change. With the UDF updating will take place only when the sheet is recalculated, and I found that not to be easily controlled.

Comment: Hi,  thanks, I realise that I hadn't attached any picture and that I was not clear enough in defining my need, I've juts added some now, also showing what I managed to get with my financial example.  Your proposed code does actually sum all the productions in the Profile table, which is not what I am after, basically and using my posted example your PROD(5, A2:B7)=32, whereas my PROD(5,A2:B7)=2 which is what I am after (ie bacteria produce 2 per week in week 4, 5, 6.  what I want in C14 is a PROD(A14:A33,$A$2:$B$7)*$B$14:$B$33*N($A$14:$A$33<=A14) type of formula... I'll continue searching.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't what you want then it should be a lot nearer to it than what I did this morning. Take a look.

```
Function PROD(Period As Range) As Single

    Dim Fun As Single
    Dim Periods As Integer
    Dim Weeks As Integer
    Dim A As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    Periods = Period.Cells.Count
    For A = 1 To Periods
        Weeks = CInt(Period.Cells(A).Value)
        With Range("Profile")
            For R = 1 To (.Rows.Count - 1)
                If .Cells(R, 1).Value >= Weeks Then Exit For
            Next R
            Fun = Fun + .Cells(R, 2).Value
        End With
    Next A
    PROD = Application.Round(Fun / Periods, 2)

End Function
```

Call this function with =Prod(A14:A20) or =Prod(A14:A14) or = Prod(A14)
It will extract one result from the Profile table for each of the specified weeks. A14:A20 will have 7 results, and so would A16:A22. The function draws an average. So, with 7 results, these seven are added up and divided by 7. Perhaps this isn't yet what you want, but you might be able to manipulate the result of the function to meet your requirements.